# How to Find Element of a Dynamic ID through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How do I go about finding an element that has a dynamic ID? I want to select `id= select_option_32` but often it will change to `select_option_60` or some other number. Any ideas?

Below is the XPATH and CSS Selector (as well as a screenshot of the script).

XPATH -

```
//*[@id="select_option_32"]
```

CSS Selector -

```
#select_option_32
```

Below is the script:

[image]

Below is the full element of the class:

```html
<md-select-menu role="presentation" class="_md md-data-studio-theme md-overflow" style="transform-origin: 65.9653px 182.222px 0px;">
   <md-content class="_md md-data-studio-theme">
      <!-- ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_76" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Fixed
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_77" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last 7 days
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_78" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last 14 days
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_79" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last 28 days
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_80" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last 30 days
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_81" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Today
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_82" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Yesterday
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_83" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This week (starts Sunday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_84" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This week to date (starts Sunday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_85" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last week (starts Sunday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_86" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This week (starts Monday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_87" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This week to date (starts Monday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_88" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last week (starts Monday)
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_89" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This month
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_90" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This month to date
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_91" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last month
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_92" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This quarter
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_93" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This quarter to date
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_94" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last quarter
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_95" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This year
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="select_option_96" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]" selected="selected">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            This year to date
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_97" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Last year
            **
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_98" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Auto date range
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in** $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions" ng-value="option" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-data-studio-theme md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_99" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]">
         <div class="md-text ng-binding">
            Advanced
         </div>
      </md-option>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: option in $ctrl.dateRangeOptions -->
   </md-content>
</md-select-menu>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to select. Are you trying to select based on text content?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS selector to locate an element using partial match :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("md-option[id^='select_option']")
```

It will locate all the option which has id starts with `select_option` So in your case to make it unique to select element specific to `select_option_32`. First get all element in list and then match the text present under

```
all_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "md-option[id^='select_option']")))
for element in all_element:
    if 'This month' in element.text:
        print("expected element is there")
        # perform your action here which you suppose to do
        break
```

Another way is indexing if you think matching text is not worthy then you can use indexed in xpath to locate fixed indexed element

```
//md-option[starts-with(@id,'select_option_')][32]
```

If you are looking for an element which is already selected then xpath would be

```
//md-option[starts-with(@id,'select_option_')][@selected='selected']
```

Comment: @Max, is this answer resolved your problem ? If yes then accept it by click tick mark on answer below vote count so it can be helpful for others. Still have query then feel free to ask ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try *starts with* functions with both XPath and CSS.

For example:

- XPath (`starts-with`): `//*[starts-with(@id,'select_option_')]`
- CSS (`^=`): `document.querySelector('*[id^="select_option_"]')`

Comment: but all the other id's also start with 'select_option' and is dynamic. How do I make it specific for that 'select_option_32'?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe that you are looking for the "Last Year" webelement. Is that correct?

Comment: No sorry, it's the 'Auto Date Range' element. It's not shown in the screenshot: <div class="md-text ng-binding">
          Auto date range
        </div>

Comment: Could you please share the whole DOM my friend. So that I can help you to resolve this issue. If application is present over the internet then please share the URL too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the partial ID along with the selected attribute:

//*[contains(@id, 'select_options_') and contains(@selected, 'selected')]

Comment: Doesn't this assume that I have that specific element selected? I'm looking for it to already be selected.

Comment: No. It will select any element that is selected and have the partial id.

Comment: but the specific ID that needs to be selected is dynamic so the _contains()_ function wouldn't work--unless I'm misunderstanding :\

Answer (score 0):

You can try with anyone of the below XPath

The below will locate you to the parent element of the Auto data range :

```
//md-content[@class='_md md-data-studio-theme']//child::md-option[23]
```

And the below one will take you exactly to the Auto date range

```
//md-content[@class='_md md-data-studio-theme']//child::md-option[23]/div[contains(text(),'Auto date range')]
```